# Catching an Integer overflow exception in Visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception, integer

How can I make the Visual studio to throw an integer overflow exception?
I know I can use a `checked` statement explicitly. But I want to make this behavior default in my solution (at least during debugging).

```
int bigNumber= 12345;
byte overflowException = (byte)(bigNumber); //want to see an exception here
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772379/making-sure-unsigned-int-long-always-execute-in-checked-context-in-c-sharp - but do have a look here as the first answer probably answers your question

Comment: @Rawling It is definitely a duplicate in terms of eventual answer, but typing in the above question title doesn't find it. So there is a little value in leaving this here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx) there is a `/checked` compiler option for turning this on as default.

> The /checked compiler option lets you specify checked or unchecked
>   context for all integer arithmetic statements that are not explicitly
>   in the scope of a checked or unchecked keyword.

In the project properties for the project, go to the "Build" tab and click the "Advanced..." button. On this window is a "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow" checkbox:

[image]

As an aside, the second set of brackets in `(byte)(bigNumber)` are not required: `(byte)bigNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the compiler "checked" option, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx